# If a device sends the parameters to apache tomcat server as a .asp and i want to access these parameters on jsp page

Tags: java, asp.net, jsp, tomcat

If a device is sending parameters to apache tomcat server as a .asp parameters and I want to access these parameters on JSP page in my project. I have already tried request.getParameter but it is showing "null".

Answer (score 0):

The request.getParameter is not gonna work as this page you are not serving and it is not in your scope.

One thing i think can work but not sure if it is optimistic approach or not but you can try this out.

You can serve this request. You can do url mapping for *.asp and then get the parameter from url and then set it on servlet and redirect to your page.

Just check if it works not sure if this helps.